# How to prevent form submission if only one out of two paired inputs is filled out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a pair of inputs. I have no problem with a user leaving the both of them blank. But what I need is a way to force the user to fill the second input field if he decides to fill the first input field and vice versa(or prevent form submission in the event of that).

Here are my input elements:

```
<input name="cas[]" id="ca">
<input name="exams[]" id="exam">

<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</submit>
```

I would also appreciate if there is also an implementation for multiple input pairs.

Comment: A little error in your button element. It should be `id="submit"` and not `id"submit"` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script like this should do the trick:

```js
var cas = document.getElementById("ca");
var exams = document.getElementById("exam");

cas.onkeyup = function() {nosubmit()}
exams.onkeyup = function() {nosubmit()}

function nosubmit() {
  if ((cas.value != "" && exams.value == "") || (cas.value == "" && exams.value != "")) {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="cas[]" id="ca">
<input name="exams[]" id="exam">

<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

### UPDATE:

For more than one pair if inputs give them a `class` name instead of (or as well as) an `id` and then do this:

```js
var cas = document.getElementsByClassName("ca");
var exams = document.getElementsByClassName("exam");
var numOfPairs = cas.length;

window.oninput = function() {
  if (nosubmit().includes("d")) {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  }
}

function nosubmit() {
  var check = ""
  for (i = 0; i < numOfPairs; i++) {
    if ((cas[i].value != "" && exams[i].value == "") || (cas[i].value == "" && exams[i].value != "")) {
      check += "d";
    } else {
      check += "e";
    }
  }
  return check
}
```

```html
<input value="" name="cas[]" class="ca">
<input value="" name="exams[]" class="exam">
<br><br>
<input value="" name="cas[]" class="ca">
<input value="" name="exams[]" class="exam">
<br><br>
<input value="" name="cas[]" class="ca">
<input value="" name="exams[]" class="exam">
<br><br>
<input value="" name="cas[]" class="ca">
<input value="" name="exams[]" class="exam">
<br><br>
<input value="" name="cas[]" class="ca">
<input value="" name="exams[]" class="exam">

<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Works here on SO, but does not work for me. Could it be because I am retrieving my input elements via ajax?

Comment: Can I see your code?

Comment: Works now. The file containing the input elements are retrieved via ajax, so I had to put in the script there instead of the main page. One more thing, this only works for one pair. Can i make it work for multiple pairs? The pairs a generated dynamically and they all have the same ```id```

Comment: Do they also have the same `name`?

Comment: yes. ```name=exams[]``` and ```name="cas[]"``` because it's gonna be submitted as an array.

Comment: you can't have more than 1 element with the same `id`, use `class` instead

Comment: once I do that, the functionality breaks. I added the classes ```ca``` and ```exam``` to the input elements, then I did ```var cas = document.getElementByClassName("ca");```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248304/discussion-between-innovin-and-johna).

Comment: `getElementById` returns an element. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. You'll need to extract the element from the array when using `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `myXOR` function to check whether the two values are different:

```
// script.js

/**
* Returns true if values are different
*/
function myXOR(a,b) {
  return (a || b) && !(a && b);
}
```

Then call it on the `change` event for either inputs, so the button is disabled if at any point only one input is filled in.

```
// page.html

<form id="form">
  <input name="cas[]" id="ca">
  <input name="exams[]" id="exam">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
// script.js

// Get elements from DOM
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
const examInput = document.querySelector("#exam");
const caInput = document.querySelector("#ca");
const button = document.querySelector("#submit");

const handleChange = e => {
  // !! to cast value to boolean
  // Will disable button if values are different, ie. if one input is filled and the other isn't
  if(myXOR(!!examInput.value, !!caInput.value)) {
    button.disabled = true;
  } else {
    button.disabled = false;
  }
}

// Listen for changes on either input
examInput.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
caInput.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
```

Comment: Okay. let me try it

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Not working. Can it be because my inputs are being shown via ajax?